# What's the meaning of "massage me up right nice"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

From an American sitcom Friends S05E13, [SOURCE HERE](http://www.livesinabox.com/friends/season5/513bag.htm)

***Monica: You know, I don't like to brag about it, but I give the best massages!***

***Chandler: All right, then massage me up right nice!***

Monica was giving massage to Chandler.

I know *massage* could be used as a verb, but what's "up right nice"? I guess maybe in here, "up" goes with "massage", and "right nice" means "very nice"? But I've searched all the dictionaries I have, still didn't find the phrase "massage up".

Comment: The dialog in Friends often used awkward wording to emphasize the awkwardness of a situation.  The character's difficulty in acting naturally is shown by their inability to speak naturally.  A similar line from another episode that comes to mind is, "I'm very happy we're going to have all the sex."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OP's context, ***up*** is entirely optional - but it wouldn't normally be used, and the statement doesn't really mean much different whether it's there or not.

Arguably there are slightly stronger *sexual* overtones to including ***up***, given that (in British English, at least) [**touch up**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/touch+up) / [**feel up**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/feel+up) can both mean *to touch or caress (someone), esp to arouse sexual feelings*.

Equally, ***right*** is just an "emphasiser" meaning ***very***, and the adjectival form ***nice*** is commonly used in informal speech where strictly speaking it should be an *adverbial* form (***nicely***).

> *"All right, then massage me up right nice!"
>
>    =
>
>     "Okay, in that case [please] massage me really well!"*

Comment: Thank you, especially for the word "up"! Now I know why he would use it.

Comment: @MarkZar: There are already strong sexual overtones to ***massage*** in the first place, and I'm sure everyone knows that many masseuses routinely offer a "de-luxe" service (including [hand relief](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hand%20relief)) for a premium price.

Comment: Yeah, I remembered that in Friends, when Phoebes first introduced herself as a masseuse, her little brother thought she was a prostitute, which is a misunderstanding. ;)

Comment: Just to add: in AmE, "feel up" has the same meaning you describe, but "touch up" means to make small changes to improve something (ex. "I touched up my makeup").

Comment: @WendiKidd: Yeah, BrE has that sense of *touch up* too. Originally I was only going to mention *touch up*, which I was pretty certain isn't very common in AmE. But in both usages, simply including ***up*** can change a neutral verb into a highly charged/sexualised slang term, which was the only reason for flagging them (up! :). On which subject, it's a moot point whether *"Cover yourself **up**!"* more strongly implies that you're showing "private" parts if you include the optional ***up***.

Comment: Nicely explained - especially the subtlety around "up". I believe that "touch up" is out of place though; that only every means "make a small correction", even in AmE. Also I have to say that in this particular answer your handle is a more than a bit appropriate... :-)

Comment: @Floris: Never say never! [Tom King](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_King_(writer)) is an American television writer and story board artist, and he wrote [*maybe they could've touched me up*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22maybe+they+could%27ve+touched+me+up%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in a context which leaves absolutely no doubt *he* knew the sexual meaning - and by implication, expected his (American) readership to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

"X me up" can be idiomatic for, roughly, "give me a X" (e.g. "call me up" for "give me a phone call").

"Right X" is just a vernacular intensifier (e.g. "get this done right quick" for "get this done without delay").

So in this case "massage me up" -> "give me a massage", "right nice" -> "do it well".

Comment: +1 Good answer Russell, some of the same stuff I was thinking about. And welcome to the ell.se!